# Prototype equivalent to jQuery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I built something using [jQuerys load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to grab a specific element from another page.

Something like :

```
$j('#result').load('http://thesite.com .desiredClass')
```

What would be an equivalent type of function with prototype?

Answer (score 3):

Look at [`Ajax.Request`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/)

```
new Ajax.Request('/your/url', {
  onSuccess: function(response) {
      var html = response.responseText;
      var div = new Element("div");
      div.innerHTML = html;
      var content = Element.select(div, ".desiredClass");
      $("content").appendChild(content);
  }
});
```

Afraid it's "lower level"

Comment: @dockworkgeek you are correct `Ajax.Updater` would be better.

Comment: I do not understand how either of these pull a defined class from the specified request.  @Raynos or clockworkgeek, can you please show the syntax for including an isolated element using these methods?

Comment: @zac try something like that. Good luck